# What could be causing these crazy pixel values when I rasterize a polygon?

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization

Here's the weird output, looks like min and max possible values for the data type?

[image: QGIS_Issue]

Here's my inputs, all pixel values should be set to 0.

[image: Details]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You set all values to zero and you specify nodata value as zero. So you get an empty raster, all pixels have nodata. Since there is no min and max value in the image to show in the legend, QGIS displays the limits of Float32 type, which is -/+3.40282..×10<sup>38</sup>

To solve the issue:

- Set nodata value different than 0,0 and
- Set pre-initialize value as 0,0:

[image]

Result:

[image]